# Doesn't pīti mean love?

Tags: jhana, pali

I am indian. And in all indian languages Priti means love. And even in abhidhamma I found a statement that it's towards the object. interest in object. Whereas sukha is from the object.

I sometime feel my breathing so comfortable that i just love/like that effortless breathing.

Isn't this pīti?

Why we made so difficult word like rapture? And making it more complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ordinary words can be converted into technical terms.

For e.g. in English, the ordinary word "reduction" means "the action or fact of making something smaller or less in amount, degree, or size".

But in medicine, a technical term was created out of "reduction" which means "the restoration of a displaced or broken part of the body to its proper position or alignment by manipulation or other surgical procedure."

So, similarly, piti may have an ordinary meaning in Pali and other Indian languages, but for jhana, the Buddha turned it into a technical term.

You can find some info in the [Rapture (*piti*) section](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/gunaratana/wheel351.html#ch3.2.3) of "[The Jhanas in Theravada Buddhist Meditation](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/gunaratana/wheel351.html)" by [Ven. Henepola Gunaratana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henepola_Gunaratana):

> ## Rapture (*piti*)
>
> The third factor present in the first *jhana* is *piti*, usually
> translated as joy or rapture. In the suttas *piti* is sometimes said
> to arise from another quality called *pamojja*, translated as joy or
> gladness, which springs up with the abandonment of the five
> hindrances. When the disciple sees the five hindrances abandoned in
> himself "gladness arises within him; thus gladdened, rapture arises in
> him; and when he is rapturous his body becomes tranquil" (D.i,73).
> Tranquillity in turn leads to happiness, on the basis of which the
> mind becomes concentrated. **Thus rapture precedes the actual arising of
> the first *jhana*, but persists through the remaining stages up to the
> third *jhana*.**
>
> The *Vibhanga* defines *piti* as "gladness, joy, joyfulness, mirth,
> merriment, exultation, exhilaration, and satisfaction of mind" (Vbh.
> 257). **The commentaries ascribe to it the characteristic of endearing,
> the function of refreshing the body and mind or pervading with
> rapture, and the manifestation as elation** ([Vism](https://www.urbandharma.org/pdf1/PathofPurification2011.pdf).143; PP.149). [Shwe Zan
> Aung](https://www.irrawaddy.com/specials/on-this-day/day-renowned-rakhine-buddhist-scholar-died.html) explains that "*piti* abstracted means interest of varying
> degrees of intensity, in an object felt as desirable or as calculated
> to bring happiness."
>
> When defined in terms of agency, *piti* is that which creates interest
> in the object; when defined in terms of its nature it is the interest
> in the object. **Because it creates a positive interest in the object,
> the *jhana* factor of rapture is able to counter and suppress the
> hindrance of ill will, a state of aversion implying a negative
> evaluation of the object.**
>
> Rapture is graded into five categories: minor rapture, momentary
> rapture, showering rapture, uplifting rapture and pervading rapture.
> Minor rapture is generally the first to appear in the progressive
> development of meditation; it is capable of causing the hairs of the
> body to rise. Momentary rapture, which is like lightning, comes next
> but cannot be sustained for long. Showering rapture runs through the
> body in waves, producing a thrill but without leaving a lasting
> impact. Uplifting rapture, which can cause levitation, is more
> sustained but still tends to disturb concentration, **The form of
> rapture most conductive to the attainment of *jhana* is all-pervading
> rapture**, which is said to suffuse the whole body so that it becomes
> like a full bladder or like a mountain cavern inundated with a mighty
> flood of water. The [*Visuddhimagga*](https://www.urbandharma.org/pdf1/PathofPurification2011.pdf) states that what is intended
> by the *jhana* factor of rapture is this all-pervading rapture "which
> is the root of absorption and comes by growth into association with
> absorption" ([Vism](https://www.urbandharma.org/pdf1/PathofPurification2011.pdf).144; PP.151)

Comment: Piti is mental cetasika.. So when you say hairs to rise.. that part is phisical. isnt it. that must be sukha feeling. isnt it?

Comment: @enRaiser No. Piti is psycho-physical. Sukha is mental only.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The right word is psychogenic. so pīti is psychogenic. I studied difference between psychosomatic and psychogenic. and found that pīti is more closed to psychogenic.

Comment: I was wondering if there is any word called phisiogenic..hahah. in that case it could mean somanassa in pali ;)

Comment: @enRaiser What's the difference between psychogenic and psychosomatic?

Comment: I think psychosomatic means that the symptoms can either be initiated from mind or body. e.g fever, hunger etc. where as for psychogenic it can only be initiated from mind like goosbump, chill etc. I am not sure..